# Why does mode switch happen in process switch?

Tags: kernel

Does `process switch` require `mode switch`? If so, why?

Comment: The question is poorly worded or insufficiently detailed.

Answer (score 5):

Process switching is the act of swapping out one process for another.

This is something that is done by the kernel (scheduler) since it's the only code that should have that level of power. User-mode code (stuff that runs outside the kernel) should not have the power to swap processes in or out.

Hence, in order to switch processes, you have to go from user mode into kernel mode. There, the process switch is done and then you will switch from kernel mode back into user mode to continue running the new process.

Comment: user mode to kernel mode is logical but why would it go vice versa?

Comment: @Fahad, it's so the new process is executing in user mode where it can't damage anything but itself.